# Is it recommended to Install and configure UFW for a new Django project on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, ufw, google-vpc

I'm deploying a new project on Google Cloud Platform using Django certified by Bitnami that comes with pre-installed Debian 9, Apache, MySQL, Python. My end goal is to build a web application, but nothing is close to production yet and I'm still running on an ephemeral external IP address assigned to the VM instance. So my question is that is it recommended that install an ufw (Uncomplicated Firewall) ?

Answer (score 1):

**There's no need to use separate firewall** because your instance is already protected by GCP firewall:

- GCP firewall blocks all incoming traffic to the instances by default unless explicitly allowed by a firewall rule;
- Rules allow incoming traffic from an IP range, a list of protocols (ICMP, TCP and UDP) and a list of ports, and they can be restricted to some instances by using [`Network tags`](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags).

More information you can find at the documentation:

- [Firewall rules overview](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls)
- [Using firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls)
- [VPC network overview](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc)

You can check current firewall rules at `VPC network` -> `Firewall rules`.